# "Catalog Search index process unknown error:" 403 Forbidden

Tags: security, elasticsearch, localhost, apache

My System info:
Apache2 /php7.4(mod-security, mod_proxy) /Mysql8 /Elastic7.10

After a fresh installation of M2.4 and configure it for the E7 with Apache proxy port 8080 to 9200. When I tried to run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` it gives me below error.

My 000default.conf file

```bash
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>

<Proxy "*">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Elastic Server"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/password/.htpasswd_elasticsearch
    Require valid-user

  # This allows OPTIONS-requests without authorization
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
        Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SecRuleEngine On
        SecRule ARGS:modsecparam "@contains test" "id:4321,deny,status:403,msg:'ModSecurity test rule has triggered'"
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Gives Error with `bin/magento indexer:reindex`:

```bash
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
```

My error.log

```bash
[Sun Jan 10 16:03:02.448075 2021] [:error] [pid 112947] [client 127.0.0.1:44628] [client 127.0.0.1] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_methods}" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "46"] [id "911100"] [msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] [data "PUT"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.2.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/viroblock_com_au_product_1_v1"] [unique_id "X-slNuyjgCLR0fle2Gi97wAAAAs"]
```

But, when I put E7 configure directly with port 9200 instead 8080 then it works fine.
I need to use port 8080 for password protected my E7.